# Exchange 2013 not receiving internally after moving database

Tags: exchange-2013

I setup an Exchange 2013 server for the internal network only. The disk I had everything was getting full, so I moved the database and log directory to a different drive.

After that, accounts can send emails but not receive them. I know it sends because emails go to the Send Items folder and disappear without receiving an error.

Maybe this is completely unrelated to moving things to a different drive, but I am not sure.

Please advise.

EDIT: I see that the Logs are not being written to the new drive because of permission error. However, I did grant full access to the Administrator.

Comment: How did you move the mailbox database and log files? Is the mailbox database mounted and healthy? Have you looked in the event logs on the Exchange server? What troubleshooting steps have you taken?

Comment: What joeqwerty said.  This is the approved method for moving the database.  http://exchangeserverpro.com/exchange-2013-move-database-to-new-folder-path/  If you just, you know, *moved it* Exchange may not know where it is.

Comment: Yes, I've used the same method. It knows where it is since it shows in ECP. Database is mounted and healthy.